# Can't decode output from BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, decoding

I've been attempting to write a little scraper in Python using BeautifulSoup. 
Everything goes smoothly until I attempt to print (or write to a file) the strings contained inside the various HTML elements. The site i'm scraping is: http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/Boots/Montreal+QC which contains various french characters. For some reason, when I attempt to print the content in the terminal or into a file, instead of decoding the string like it's supposed to, I'm getting the raw unicode output. 
Here's the script:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib as ul
##import re

base_url = 'http://www.yellowpages.ca'
data_file = open('yellow_file.txt', 'a')

data = ul.urlopen(base_url + '/locations/Quebec/Montreal/90014002.html').readlines()

bt = bs(str(data))

result = bt.findAll('div', 'ypgCategory')

bt = bs(str(result))

result = bt.findAll('a')

for tag in result:
    link = base_url + tag['href']
    ##print str(link)
    data = ul.urlopen(link).readlines()

    #data = str(data).decode('latin-1')
    bt = bs(str(data), convertEntities=bs.HTML_ENTITIES, fromEncoding='latin-1')
    titles = bt.findAll('span', 'listingTitle')
    phones = bt.findAll('a', 'phoneNumber')

    entries = zip(titles, phones)

    for title, phone in entries:
        #print title.prettify(encoding='latin-1')
        #data_file.write(title.text.decode('utf-8') + "   " + phone.text.decode('utf-8') + "\n")
        print title.text

data_file.close()
```

/************************/

And the output of this is:  Projets Autochtones Du Qu\xc3\xa9bec

As you can see the e with accent that's supposed to go in Quebec isn't displaying. I've tried everything mentioned on SO, calling unicode(), passing fromEncoding to soup, .decode('latin-1') but i'm getting nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you *want* the output to be?

Comment: I'd like the decode operation to translate the Unicode entities into readable characters, for example: "Québec"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be something like what you want:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib as ul

base_url = 'http://www.yellowpages.ca'
data_file = open('yellow_file.txt', 'a')

bt = bs(ul.urlopen(base_url + '/locations/Quebec/Montreal/90014002.html'))

for div in bt.findAll('div', 'ypgCategory'):
    for a in div.findAll('a'):
        link = base_url + a['href']

        bt = bs(ul.urlopen(link), convertEntities=bs.HTML_ENTITIES)

        titles = bt.findAll('span', 'listingTitle')
        phones = bt.findAll('a', 'phoneNumber')

        for title, phone in zip(titles, phones):
            line = '%s   %s\n' % (title.text, phone.text)
            data_file.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
            print line.rstrip()

data_file.close()
```

Comment: This is interesting. I tried your version, and now when it prints in the terminal it works perfectly, but when i look at the file, the strings contain the same raw output as before, and even more strange is that the html entities are present in the file as well. I tried changing the encode to decode, but that gave me a new error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Ok, thanks to your direction i found a working solution. It turns out that to write Unicode strings into a file you need to open the file with codecs.open('filename', 'mode', 'utf-8'). Once this was done, everything worked without a hitch. Thanks again!

Comment: @Steve. Are you sure you're opening the file as "utf-8" in your text editor? It works perfectly fine for me. I'm also not seeing any html entities (although I only looked at the first two thousand lines).

Comment: Also, i changed the file opening call to this: 
data_file = codecs.open( "yellow_file.txt", "a", "utf-8" )

And the last 2 lines of the innermost for loop to this:
data_file.write(line.rstrip())
print line.rstrip()

Answer (score 0):

Who told you to use `latin-1` to decode something that is `UTF-8`? (clearly specified on the meta tag)

1. If you ware on Windows you may have problems outputting Unicode to console, better to test writing to text files first.
2. if you open a file as text do no write binary to it:

   - `codecs.open(...,"w","utf-8").write(unicode_str)`
   - `open(...,"wb").write(unicode_str.encode("utf_8"))`

Comment: I've actually tried all of the above with utf-8 first, but when that didn't work i made attempts at latin-1. My bad.